# The term 'xWebsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, dsc

I installed `xWebAdministration` module. For some reason I am still getting this error message

> The term 'xWebsite' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

[image]

image url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTwUe.jpg

here's my code.

```
Configuration MvcWebTest {

    Param(
        [String[]]$ComputerName = "tvw-irwebsvc",
        $AppName = "MvcWebTest",
        $User = "PAOMSvc",
        $Password = "Welcome1",
        $CodePath = "C:\websites\MvcWebTest"

    )

    Import-DscResource -Module xWebAdministration

    Node $ComputerName {

        #Install ASP.NET 4.5
        WindowsFeature ASP {
            Ensure = “Present”
            Name = “Web-Asp-Net45”
        }

        File WebContent {
            Ensure ="Present";
            SourcePath ="\\DVW-MORBAM01\Build\Publish\MvcWebTest\Dev";
            DestinationPath=$CodePath;
            Type = "Directory";
            Recurse = $True
        }

        # Create a new website 
        xWebsite Website { 
            Ensure          = "Present";
            Name            = $AppName;
            State           = "Started";
            PhysicalPath    = $CodePath;
            DependsOn       = "[File]WebContent" 
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screenshot is showing you the problem: The `xWebsite` resource isn't installed. Only the `xwebApplication` and `xWebVirtualDirectory` resources are installed.

I just downloaded the `xWebAdministration` 1.3.2.3 zip file from [Technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xWebAdministration-Module-3c8bb6be), and it looks like someone made a boo-boo -- it's missing `xWebSite`! The Q&A section is full of people upset about it, so you're not alone. :)

Oddly enough, the Wave 9 resource kit that supposedly includes all the modules has the same problem!

The easiest way to get past this is to just grab version [1.3.2](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/xWebAdministration-Module-3c8bb6be/file/131368/1/xWebAdministration_1.3.2.zip), which looks like it has everything.

Answer (score -1):

To enact the configuration, run the following command:

```
Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Verbose -Path .\MvcWebTest
```

This cmdlet is part of the DSC system. The Wait parameter is optional and makes the cmdlet run interactively. Without this parameter, the cmdlet will create and return a job.

Comment: While true, this isn't the problem.